# How to find the probability of one sample variance is two times larger than another?

Tags: variance, chi-squared, anova

I have two normal distribution where $X\sim N(\mu_{x}, 40^{2})$ and $Y\sim N(\mu_{y}, 50^{2})$. 8 samples from X and 16 samples from Y is drawn. How to determine the probability that the variance of the first sample is more than twice that of the second?


At first I was thinking about Chi-square distribution, but it seems that it only works for checking one variance.


Any help would be appreciated.


Edit:
I now reached to something like $\frac{25S_{X}^{2}}{16S_{Y}^2}\sim F_{7, 15}$,
then I am trying to calculate $P(S_{X}^{2}>2S_{Y}^2)$
$$\begin{eqnarray} 
P(S_{X}^{2}>2S_{Y}^2) &=& P(\frac{S_{X}^{2}}{S_{Y}^2}>2) \\
&=& P(\frac{25S_{X}^{2}}{16S_{Y}^2}>2(\frac{25}{16})) \\
&=& P(\frac{25S_{X}^{2}}{16S_{Y}^2}>3.125)\\
&=& 1 - F_{7, 15}(3.125)
\end{eqnarray}$$
Am I doing it correct? I am trying to lookup the value from the table but where's the alpha-value (significance value)

Comment: do the reverse procedure, start with set $\mathbb{P}[S_{X}^2>2S_{Y}^2]$ and express this probability in terms of $\frac{15}{7}\frac{U}{V}$ where U and V are specified below

Comment: @tommik I have just updated my work

Comment: @IceLemonTea: you are right. The significance value is the probability you are looking for...not all the tables get all the values....you can use a Calculator, leave the result you get or read a nearerst value in the table

Comment: @tommik okay, will try it, thanks for your help!

Comment: My table gives $1-F_{(7;15)}(3.29)=2.5$%. Your numerical result shoul be a bitter great. With the calculator the exact probability value is about 3.03%

Comment: @tommik I have used this [online calculator](http://onlinestatbook.com/2/calculators/F_dist.html) and yes, it gives me 3.03%

Comment: If this is an exercise I think that you have not to use the calculator, simply conclude that the probability is a bit more than 2.5%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I underline that X and Y must be independent.

Hint:

$U=\frac{7S_X^2}{40^2}\sim \chi_{(7)}^2$

$V=\frac{15S_Y^2}{50^2}\sim \chi_{(15)}^2$

...but you know that $\frac{\frac{U}{7}}{\frac{V}{15}}=\frac{15}{7}\frac{U}{V}$ follows a  Snedercor's F Distribution....

...now I think you can go on by youself

Comment: Thanks for your hint.
I will work on it and ask again if I have questions